# How to init $location at config

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi my question is how do i initialize the $location at my module configuration. I need to gather the base url that's why i need it for routes.

```
var templateApp = angular.module("tmpApp",["ngRoute"]);
templateApp.config(function($routeProvider){
console.log('$location',$location.$$absUrl);
$routeProvider
  .when("/", {
    templateUrl: $location.url() + "/testajax"
  })
  .when("/register", {
    templateUrl: "ajax here",
    controller: "registerApp"
  });
});
```

Comment: inject it like how you are injecting `$routeProvider`

Comment: from `https://website.com/some?path` you can extract your base/host with `$location.host()`, which will give you `website.com` ($location is not a global service, so you need to inject it into config)

Comment: I added it as param in the function as routeProvider but still gives error the same

Comment: @Enigma errors are good, they tell you what went wrong, can you post that error here? (_edit your question_)

Comment: When i add function($routeProvider,$location) at the config i get  this error: Error: $injector:modulerr
Module Error, Failed to instantiate module tmpApp due to:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting an error because you cannot inject a `service` directly into the configuration block as the services won't be initialized there. You can only use `providers` inside the config block, so using `$locationProvider` instead of `$location` will do the trick. Doc's [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$locationProvider#$locationProvider-methods)